# How to use the values of input json configurations passed to trigger the airflow job inside the dag?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, airflow

I am new to airflow and working on a use case where I need to read the input json configs that are passed to an airflow dag and construct a string based on the configs read, this string will be used as the name of cluster we are creating in GCP data proc.

Ex :
Input Json to dag

{
"x" : "data",
"y": "engg",
"z" : "usecase"
}

I am expecting the cluster name to be "my-cluster-for-data-engg-usecase"
with the code below but I am getting an error like it cannot recognize "dag_run". Any help would be appreciated.

```
from datetime import datetime
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow import models
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago

CONN_ID = 'blah'
PROJECT_ID = 'xyz'
REGION = 'us-east4'
CLUSTER_NAME = "my-cluster-for-"+dag_run.conf['x']+dag_run.conf['y']+dag_run.conf['z']
with models.DAG('simple-python-dag', start_date=days_ago(1), schedule_interval=None) as dag:


    create_cluster_spark = XyzCreateClusterOperator(task_id='create_cluster_spark',
                                                    cluster_name=CLUSTER_NAME,
                                                    location=REGION,
                                                    gcp_conn_id=CONN_ID)

    create_cluster_spark
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dag_run` is only available in an active DAG run (i.e when you've triggered the DAG and it is running) - specifying `dag_run.conf` as an object will not work as the Airflow scheduler will parse your dags (every 30s by default) and no such object exists.

There are two ways access the `dag_run`:

1. Use the templating system

```
CLUSTER_NAME = "my-cluster-for-{{ dag_run.conf['x'] }}{{ dag_run.conf['y'] }}{{ dag_run.conf['z'] }}"
```

This will only work if the `cluster_name` field is a templated field in the `XyzCreateClusterOperator` Operator. You can check if a field is templated by looking at the docstring, or looking at the Airflow [documentation](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/operators/index.html) for operators.

If `XyzCreateClusterOperator` is a third party provider you can check the documentation for the provider [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/#providers-packages-docs-apache-airflow-providers-index-html)

You can see all available items in a template [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/templates-ref.html) (`dag_run` is one of many things you can access using this template syntax).

2. You can access the `dag_run` inside a python operator

```py
import pendulum
from airflow.decorators import dag, task

@dag(
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=pendulum.datetime(2022, 4, 18),
    catchup=False,
)
def example_dag():
    @task()
    def dag_run_example_task(**context):
        context["dag_run"].conf.get("x")
        context["dag_run"].conf.get("y")
        context["dag_run"].conf.get("z")
```

If `cluster_name` is not a templated field, you can use the Python Operator to wrap around your operator and substitute in:

```py
import pendulum
from airflow.decorators import dag, task

@dag(
    schedule_interval=None,
    start_date=pendulum.datetime(2022, 4, 18),
    catchup=False,
)
def example_dag():
    @task()
    def dag_run_example_task(**context):
        cluster_name = "my-cluster-for-"+context["dag_run"].conf.get("x")+context["dag_run"].conf.get("y")+context["dag_run"].conf.get("z")

        create_cluster_spark = XyzCreateClusterOperator(
            task_id='create_cluster_spark',
            cluster_name=cluster_name,
            location=REGION,
            gcp_conn_id=CONN_ID,
        )

        create_cluster_spark.execute(context=context)
```

The same objects available in the templates [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/templates-ref.html) are available in the `context` object passed to a PythonOperator (and a few more as well).

Comment: Awesome information ! Worked templating system well for me. Thanks @DanielT